# incompatible Objective-c types warning

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a user class that I use through the iPhone application, this is the init and initWithUser functions from my user class (A SUBCLASS OF NSobject), when I use the initWithUser function I get the warning described after the code. please advise.

```
// serialize.h 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol Serialize

// serialize the object to an xml string
-(NSString*)ToXML;

@end


// user.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Serialize.h"
#import "Contact.h"


@interface User : NSObject <Serialize> {

NSString *email;
NSString *firstName;
NSString *lastName;
NSString *userId;
NSString *userName;
NSString *password;

NSMutableArray *contactList;

}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *userId;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *contactList;

//-(id)init;
-(id)initWithUser:(User *)copyUser;

@end



// user.m 
#import "user.h"


@implementation User

@synthesize email;
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize userId;
@synthesize userName;
@synthesize password;
@synthesize contactList;

-(id)init
{
    // call init in parent and assign to self
    if( (self = [super init]) ) 
    {          
        // do something specific 
        contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithUser:(User *)copyUser
{
    if( (self = [self init]) ) {           

        email               = copyUser.email;
        firstName           = copyUser.firstName;
        lastName            = copyUser.lastName;
        userId              = copyUser.userId;
        userName            = copyUser.userName;
        password            = copyUser.password;

        // release contactList initialized in the init
        [contactList release];
        contactList         = [copyUser.contactList mutableCopy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // TODO: 
    [contactList removeAllObjects];
    [contactList release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// implementation of serialize protocol
-(NSString*)ToXML
{
    return @""; 
}
```

and I use it in the main controller this way

```
- (void) registerNewUser {

    RegistrationViewController *regController = [[RegistrationViewController alloc] init] ;

    regController.newUser = [[User alloc] initWithUser:self.user];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:regController animated:YES];
    [regController release];

}
```

the line

```
regController.newUser = [[User alloc] initWithUser:self.user];
```

gives me the following error, and its been driving me nuts for a couple of days:

> incompatible Objective-c types 'struct User*', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'initWithUser:' from distinct Objective-c type

any help and guidance is appreciated

Comment: Mmm. Could you post the `User.h` file?

Comment: What does `Serialize` look like? Do you have any weird categories of `NSObject`? Any `#define` that could be involved?

Comment: I added the serialize code above, no #define or anything like that

Comment: Very strange indeed, I get the same error, but simply renaming the `initWithUser:` method to `initWithAUser:` makes the warning disappear.  Though even with the original name it does call the correct method at runtime.

Comment: Some follow-up notes: Reusing the `-init` is redundant here. The ivar assignments like `email` should be `copy` or `retain`. `[contactList removeAllObjects]` is redundant. Finally, as mentioned before, `newUser` is over-retained, the instance has to be released after invoking the property setter.

Comment: Georg, would you be kind enough to provide an implementation for your user that showcases your comment? I am still learning objective-c, and some stuff is still not obvious. thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you have an ambiguous selector. Because `alloc` returns `id`, the call to `initWithUser:` has become ambiguous. `NSUserDefaults` also has an `initWithUser:` function which takes a string. The compiler thinks you're trying to use that one. Change the line to

```
regController.newUser = [(User*)[User alloc] initWithUser:self.user];
```

and everything should work as expected.

Comment: thank you so much, I changed the name to initWithAUser to remove the ambiguity. I wouldnt have thought of that, you saved me a lot of frustration. and thank you all for helping out.

Comment: Good call. Seems to me that the compiler warning should be able to spell out that it's ambiguous, not that the argument is of the wrong type since there's no particular reason to prefer NSUserDefault over User.

Comment: I think Clang might have a better warning for this case. In a perfect world it would be able to see what type you're assigning to and pick the right selector that returns that type.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are other problems with your implementation. In your initializer, reusing the `-init` is redundant and the assignments to ivars like `email` should be taking ownership of the data using `-copy` or `-retain`:

```
-(id)initWithUser:(User *)copyUser {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        // take ownership of the users data by copying or retaining:
        email = [copyUser.email copy];
        // ...

        contactList = [copyUser.contactList mutableCopy];
    }    
    return self;
}
```

In `-dealloc`, `-removeAllObjects` can be removed and the member data has to be released:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [email release];
    // ...

    [contactList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that you are also leaking the new `User` instance if `newUser` is a `copy` or `retain` property as there is a `release` missing:

```
User *user = [[User alloc] initWithUser:self.user];
regController.newUser = user;
[user release];
```